# Error in job agent when running a package in SSISDB catalog (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created a simple package in visual studio. Then I deployed this package in SSISDB catalog which is on a different server. I am using Job agent to execute this package with a proxy account. But I am getting this error in Job Agent:

"**Excuted as user: ***\test**. Microsoft (R) SQL Server execute Package Utility Version 13.0.5153.0 for 64-bit Copyright 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved. Failed to execute IS server package because of error **0x80131904**. Server: ****, Package path: ****.dtsx , Environment reference Id: NULL. **Description: Login failed for user: '***\test'**. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider. .... The package execution failed. The step failed."

Kindly help me with identifying this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by giving the user access to the catalog.